# How do i display on render instead of console.log in node.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I have already sorted the objects like the link below. My next step is to be able to use the sorted object to display on my render rather than just `console.log()`.

I'm not sure if putting it back into an object is the approach. Would appreciate if anyone can help me out. Thanks

```js
var byLikes = [
  { name: 'herman', Like: 5 },
  { name: 'tabitha', Like: 3 },
  { name: 'juags', Like: 1 },
  { name: 'ukiq', Like: 4 },
  { name: 'limau', Like: 10 },
  { name: 'kwe', Like: 6 }
];

byLikes.sort(sortByLike);

function sortByLike(a, b) {
  var result = 0;
  if (a.Like > b.Like) { result = 1; }
  if (b.Like > a.Like) { result = -1; }
  return result;
}

byLikes.forEach(function (cat) {
  console.log(cat);
});

res.render('reload', { imglikes: sortedlikedhere, postername: sortednamehere });
```

Answer (score 0):

`byLikes` can be passed to `render` method as below. In the template, it can be accessed via `imglikes` property.

```
res.render('reload', {
  imglikes: byLikes, 
  postername: sortednamehere
});
```